# LumenWorks.CsvReader: How to read Decimal using invariant culture?

Tags: c#, csv, lumenworks

I am reading CSV files using `LumenWorks.CsvReader`. It works fine when I do not try to prescribe a `Decimal` type column like this:

```
cols = new List<Column>  {
     new Column { Name="client", Type=typeof(string) },
     new Column { Name="gross_sell", Type=typeof(Decimal) }
}
```

... and reading into a `DataTable` like this:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
using (StreamReader stream = new StreamReader(csvFileName, encoding))
using (CsvReader reader = new CsvReader(stream, hasHeaders, delimiter))
{
    reader.Columns = cols;
    dt.Load(reader);
}
```

The problem is that it fails on values like `42.53` telling me that the input string has bad format. The default culture info says it should be `42,53`.

How can I tell to `LumenWorks.CsvReader` that it should use invariant culture in the case?

Comment: I haven't used that library in order to read files but I guess you could perform a `Decimal.TryParse` manually providing the desired culture. Anyway, I use to choose FileHelpers for reading/writing. Give it a try, works like a charm.

Comment: @Gonzo345 Well, I know more ways how to parse string to Decimal. What I need to know is how can I pass the information to the `LumenWorks.CsvReader`.